# Selection sort ascending

Tags: c++

That is my function:

```
int main() {
    double data[100];

    int num;

    cout<<"num= ";
    cin>>num;

    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        cout<<i<<" element = ";
        cin>>data[i];
    }

    Sort(data, num);

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        cout<<data[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void Sort(double data[], int n) {
    int i,j,k;
    double min;

    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        k = i;
        min = data[k];

        for(j = i+1; j < n; j++)
            if(data[j] < min) {
                k = j;
                min = data[k];
            }
        data[k] = data[i];
        data[i] = min;
    }
}
```

if I write for exp. three elements: 8,9,1 again cout 8,9,1?

Comment: Did you steph through your code to see what was happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) { // WRONG
```

I think you mean:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) { // RIGHT
```

Arrays in C are 0-indexed remember.

Answer (score 1):

Your sorting function is fine. The only problem is that you enter elements at positions `1` through `n`, inclusive, while you should use `0` through `n-1`, inclusive, in both loops of the `main()` function.

If you need to print numbers `1` through `n`, use

```
cout<<(i+1)<<" element = ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get used of the 0 index begin in the for loop
`for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)`

so fixing these two index errors will make your code run properly.

**the reason is:**

if you write data to `data[]` using `1` as the begining, your data array's first item will be a random number:

if you insert 3 elements, the array will be like this:

```
data[0] = ??? // maybe a very very big number
data[1] = 8
data[2] = 9
data[3] = 1
```

and in your Sort function, your index begins at 0 and ends before `num`, that means your code would only sort `data[0], data[1], data[2]`.

if you use: num = 3, 3 2 1 as your input data for the origin code you could see that 3 and 2 is sorted

I guess your Sort code is googled from somewhere, please try to understand it.

Good online algorithm course: https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI

a very good algorithm online book: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/

btw, `for(j = i+1; j < n; j++)` in the `Sort` function would be better if it has `{` `}` braces.